# ZF2 : Call a service from an external class?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, service-factory

In my Zend Framework 2 project, I have an external lib and I want to save my information in the base with the model.

....
....
....

**EDITED MESSAGE :**

I explain again my need: In my controllers, I make insertions and deletions in the database and I want to log all actions in a "t_log" table . To do it, I have thought to create an external class.

My question is: How I can call my models method from my external class ?

```
namespace Mynamespace;

use Firewall\Model\Logs;
use Firewall\Model\LogsTable;

class StockLog
{
    public function addLog()
    {
       $log = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Firewall\Model\LogTable');
       $log->save('user added'); 
       die('OK');
    }
}
```

My model :

```
namespace Firewall\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class UserGroupTable
{

    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // How I Can call this method from the StockLog method ?
    }
}
```

Thanks you !

Comment: add your modules in the application.config.php   'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Firewall',

    ),

Comment: It's not a module.. ? I have edited my message. :)

Comment: What i think is you need to create the factories in the local module.php and then you can access the service

Comment: 'Firewall\Model\LogTable' => function($sm) {
          $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
          $table = new LogTable($dbAdapter);
          return $table;
         },

Comment: in your controller use like this  public function getLogTable() {
        if (!$this->logTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->logTable = $sm->get('Firewall\Model\LogTable');
        }
        return $this->logTable;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getServiceLocator` is a function of  `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` so it is supposed to be used in your controllers.

I dont know what your `StockLog`  class is, but it is not extending any other class, so i guess it has not that function and your error is one step before, in the call to `getSErviceLocator` that is not defined, so its not returning an object.

Probably you can inject the service locator with something like

```
class StockLog 
{

  private $serviceLocator= null;

  public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
  }


    public function add()
    {
       # Do you know how I can call the service ??
       $User = $this->serviceLocator->get('Firewall\Model\UserTable');
    }


}
```

and then, when you create your StockLog object, in your controller, you inject the servicelocator

```
public class yourController extends AbstractActionController {

   public function yourAction(){
      $mStockLog = new StockLog ();
       $mStockLog->setServiceLocator($this->getServiceLocator()); 
    /...

   }
}
```

Also, if you only need the  `'Firewall\Model\UserTable'` service, you should inject just that, instead of the serviceLocator.

At any rate you should minimice the knowledge of your model classes about the rest of the system, hving always in mind the [dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), to get a better [decoupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)

**UPDATE**

inject the log table

```
namespace Mynamespace;

use Firewall\Model\Logs; use Firewall\Model\LogsTable;

class StockLog {


 private $logTable= null;

  public function setLogTable($logTable)
  {
    $this->logTable= $logTable;
  }

public function addLog()
{

   $this->logTable->save('user added'); 
   die('OK');
}
```

}

and then, when you create your StockLog (in your controller, or wherever you do it, before you use it)  you inject the logtable object

```
  $mStockLog = new StockLog ();
  $mStockLog->setLogTable($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Firewall\Model\LogTable'));
```

Of course, Im suposing that you configured correctly your `Firewall\Model\LogTable` class to be retrieved by means of the service manager, in  `getServiceConfig()` in your `Module.php`

```
  public function getServiceConfig() {
       return array (
            'factories' => array (
                    'Firewall\Model\LogTable' => function ($sm) {
                         $logTable = //create it as you use to  
                  return $logTable;
            }  

        )

  }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I have edited the topic, there was confuse. :)

Comment: my code is just a snippet to illustrate how to inject the servicelocator. You have to adapt it to your real system!

Comment: Read my update, and try to do it in your code. where do you instantiate your StockLog class? if you do what i propose, what further errors are you getting?

Comment: @djay they say that in ZF3 (that is still many, many months ahead) the will go even one step forward. They want to avoid $this->getServiceLocator() to be called inside Controllers, bringing dependency injection as far as they can. [reference](http://samminds.com/2013/10/understanding-zend-framework-3-before-its-out/)

Comment: Thanks you Carlos ! You are a ZF Pro !!